# BFS All Unique Paths - Most efficient way to track visited nodes?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, search, breadth-first-search, maze

I've implemented BFS in Python3 to find all unique paths from a start coordinate to an end coordinate in a maze, but I'm unsure of the most efficient way to check if a node has been visited in a given iteration.

I've tried both what seems to be the standard list implementation of keeping track of previously traversed nodes as well as an OrderedDict implementation. My question is in the "valid_neighbors" step and checking if a neighbor already exists in the traversed path.

With a standard list implementation, lookup would be O(n) where n is the length of the traversed path. With the OrderedDict implementation, lookups should be roughly O(1) (by my understanding), but the OrderedDict is rehashed at each iteration which is an expensive O(n) operation.

```
from collections import deque, OrderedDict, namedtuple
from typing import List

Coordinate = namedtuple('Coordinate', ('x', 'y'))

def bfs_matrix(maze: List[List[int]],
                      start: Coordinate,
                      end: Coordinate) -> List[List[Coordinate]]:
    """First path is the shortest."""
    queue: deque[OrderedDict[Coordinate, Coordinate]] = deque()

    queue.append(OrderedDict({start: start}))
    paths: List[OrderedDict[Coordinate, Coordinate]] = []

    while queue:
        path: OrderedDict[Coordinate, Coordinate] = queue.popleft()
        # path: List[Coordinate] = queue.popleft()
        # node: Coordinate = path[-1]
        node: Coordinate = next(reversed(path))
        # visited = set(path)
        if node == end:
            paths.append(path)
        else:
            neighbors = map(Coordinate,
                            (node.x-1, node.x+1, node.x, node.x),
                            (node.y, node.y, node.y-1, node.y+1))
            valid_neighbors = [C for C in neighbors if
                               0 <= C.x < len(maze) and 
                               0 <= C.y < len(maze[0]) and
                               C not in path]

            for neighbor in valid_neighbors:
                # new_path: List[Coordinate] = list(path)
                new_path: OrderedDict[Coordinate, Coordinate] = OrderedDict(path)
                # new_path.append(neighbor)
                new_path[neighbor] = neighbor
                queue.append(new_path)
    return paths
```

I get all of the unique paths using this algorithm and it seems to run fairly quickly, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to check the membership condition for newly traversed nodes.

Comment: Is there any reason why the search must be a BFS instead of DFS? I'm fairly certain DFS search could be optimized to run much faster, and without using any `O(n)` time operations involving `OrderedDict`s or `List`s

Comment: @DillonDavis Only for my own understanding. I know that in general, BFS is used when we're interested in the minimum path while DFS is often used otherwise because implementation is usually simpler. I would just like to understand the best way to set things up if I had to use BFS here for some reason.